# How to Modify Sprite Class in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, prototype, sprite

I want to add some more functionality to Sprite class in ActionScript-3. Basically adding variables and methods. I've got this working solution which I don't like much because I need to reference Sprite by its full path:

```
package myPackage
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import myPackage.Sprite;

    public class Sprite extends flash.display.Sprite
    {
        public function Sprite()
        {
            super();
            graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xff00ff);
            graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 64, 64);
            doStuff();
        }

        public function doStuff(): void
        {
            trace("hello world");
            if (Math.random() < 0.9)
                addChild(new myPackage.Sprite());
        }
    }
}
```

Missing imports gave me these errors although Java compiler can deal well without those 2 imports:

- Error: Ambiguous reference to Sprite.
- Error: The definition of base class Sprite was not found.

**Is there another way to add variables, properties and methods to Sprite and use the new Sprite as class afterwards ? If prototyping, is there a simple and easy example ?**

Comment: Just change your class name so something that is not also used by Flash - you can have multiple classes with the same name but its not recommended and guessing you are reasonably new to OOD, its a lot easier to keep names distinct

Comment: "reasonably new to OOD" ? You maybe ? Name conflicts is nothing new in programming. That's why namespaces and packages were invented!

Comment: sorry if i offended you - just the impression i got from your question

Comment: @Lee Burrows No, you just looked at the reputation thing when I have/had 1 point. But it means/meant #1 ^^

Answer (score 0):

I recommend picking another class name for your subclass. Even if you find a way to replace Adobe's Sprite with your own, this is a bad idea. Also, unless you have the source code for an existing subclass of Sprite, I recommend against trying to change it directly (eg. recompiling as a child of your Sprite class rather than Adobe's Sprite class).

Sprite is a very commonly used class, and you will probably want another developer to be able to follow your code some day. If you use 'EnhancedSprite' or similar, it will be obvious that there is more/different functionality available.

It is obvious why you need to use the full class path when you try to use the same class name. This will always be the case within your Sprite/EnhancedSprite file. If you really must use the name 'Sprite', You need to find a way to have your actionscript compiler import all of the Adobe classes except Sprite, plus your own sprite class.

If you want all sprite subclasses to extend from your improved class, you basically need to recompile them all (MovieClip being the big one I personally don't mess with under the hood). This is also a bad idea, because an existing subclass could have a method matching the name of your own method and would cause further problems. For example, if you have a method stop(), how will MovieClip be compiled? Before using 'doStuff' as a method name, you would have to check that no existing subclass of Sprite already has that as a method or variable name, whether public or private.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need this line in your myPackage.Sprite class :

```
import myPackage.Sprite;
```

Likely what is happening is that in whatever class you are creating an instance of this Sprite, you have both Sprite classes imported, but you are not specifying the package explicitly in that class.

For example if in your Main class you have these imports :

```
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import myPackage.Sprite;
```

You need to be explicit wherever you use that class name. If you are not, you'll likely get the error you have been getting.

For example, this will give you that error if you have both imported :

```
var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite;
```

You should instead do the following wherever appropriate :

```
var mySprite:myPackage.Sprite = new myPackage.Sprite;
var regSprite:flash.display.Sprite = new flash.display.Sprite;
```

Also, are you compiling with CS6 or Flash Builder or Flash Develop ?